# Is it a good practice to write raw sql query in Nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Raw sql query as in:

```
var sql = "update node SET changed = " + params.updationTime + " where nid = " + params.nid
```

Is it recommended to write raw sql query in our .js file ? Are we prone to any SQL injection ? Or will it better to use library such as Knex.js ?

Comment: raw query like above will be prone to sql injection

Comment: will knex be better in this case ?

Comment: have you tried quotes

Answer (score 9):

I am in the camp that prefer the RAW parameter queries in code because of following reasons

1. Simplicity: writing the direct SQL query is the simplest way to interact with DB in it's native way.
2. Complexity of ORM: learning an ORM is basically adding another layer of complexity in your projects. You have to learn and master the ORM because you can accomplish anything professional in a project. This layer and knowledge does not translate to other platforms like if you switch from Node to .NET C#. Native SQL knowledge can go from one platform to other without any learning
3. ORM is just a pain when you need to write some custom complex queries. Not all queries can easily be written in ORM and usually you end up hacking around the ORM.
4. ORM puts another layer of complexity on top of your already complex code. I personally prefer simplicity when developing software
5. ORM is just another layer between your code and DB and many of the ORM queries suffers from degrade performance
6. In big projects the ORM becomes a bottleneck instead of benefiting. Like you cannot hire a experienced developer if one of the developer leaves the project. As PM you have to calculate how quickly a replacement is available and usually finding a specific ORM engineer is difficult. Usually PM then hire somebody who they train over time. Also newly converted ORM developers produce buggy or non-professional codes

Having said that there are benefits of using ORM against RAW queries. Some of them are structured way to interact with DB and security. Security issue can be handled in RAW queries by parameterizing the queries

Comment: I have just run in to problems with sequelize, I like the visibility 'raw sql', understanding what's going on when calling the DB, its easier and quicker to debug and adapt the call,  but this is also probably due to being new in development c.1 year experience. My issues occur do to lack of support for es6 modules with sequelize and on top becoming disillusioned with complex associations not working and my frustration in then trying to debug. My plan is now to re-factor my code and use traditional queries, its probably a days worth of work but one that will save me time in the future. cheers

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the points from Shahzad Aslam.  I'd add that you can go a bit above and beyond writing plain strings in your Node.js application.  I prefer to write my queries as `.sql` files and then parse them into parameterized queries (to avoid sql injection) at runtime.  Here's an [example](https://github.com/mmckelvy/pg-query) (the example is for the Node-Postgres client but should be similar for MySQL).

The upside of writing your queries as actual `sql` is you get modularity, syntax highlighting, and the ability to run your queries directly against the database with your preferred database client/tool (which is great for performance analysis and debugging).

Answer (score 1):

[Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) is nice ORM for node and mysql. However, if an app requires one or two queries you can escape your variables. 
Also, template literals variables will be cleaner than old string concatenation method.

```
var sql = `update node SET changed ${params.updationTime} where nid = ${params.nid}`
```

According to mysql driver [docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)

> In order to avoid SQL Injection attacks, you should always escape any
>   user provided data before using it inside a SQL query. You can do so
>   using the `mysql.escape()`, `connection.escape()` or `pool.escape()`

```
 var sql = `update node SET changed ${mysql.escape(params.updationTime)} where nid = ${mysql.escape(params.nid)}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the database handle and store database logic, use [stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score -1):

It's better for using `ORM(Object Relational Mapping)` instead of Raw query but when the query becomes complicate you should use raw query and beware `SQL injection`.